# htaccess redirect with and without parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I am trying to do the following redirect:

- If the user comes from: `www.example.com/folder/sub-folder/`, it will be redirect to `www.example.com/filehtml.html`

  This is working correctly.
- If the user comes from: `www.example.com/folder/sub-folder/index.html`, it will be redirected to `www.example.com/filehtml.html`

  This is not working.
- If the user comes from: `www.example.com/folder/sub-folder/?id=1&id2=2`, it will be redirected to `www.example.com/filehtml.html?id=1&id2=2`

  This is working correctly.
- If the user comes from: `www.example.com/folder/sub-folder/index.html?id=1&id2=2`, it will be redirected to `www.example.com/filehtml.html?id=1&id2=2`

  This is not working.

---

```
Redirect 301 /folder/sub-folder/ /filehtml.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.site\.pt$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^folder/sub-folder/index\.html$ http://www.example.com/filehtml.html%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC]
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Replace all of your code with this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^folder/sub-folder/ /filehtml.html [L,NC,R=302]
```

QUERY_STRING is automatically carried over to `/filehtml.html`.

- Make sure this is placed in root .htaccess
- Make sure this is very first rule

Comment: Doesnt work. I have alot of rules on my htaccess, where some need to be similar to this example.

Comment: As I suggested, this needs to be placed as first rule and must be in root .htaccess. Do you have .htaccess in `/folder/` or `/folder/sub-folder/` also?